# Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error during copying

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error after copying the 24th (always 24!) record using a range (the first 24 records in the range copy correctly). When I use `EntireRow` for the copy, the macro works fine and completes correctly.

Debug shows the error occurs in `cell.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 15).Copy`, whereas `cell.EntireRow.Copy` works fine.

There is nothing different between rows 24, 25, 26, etc. and I have deleted rows to make sure none is corrupt - no change :-(

Unfortunately, I do not want to copy the entire row, because this prevents me from offsetting to a different column when pasting the data, which I need to do for an action I want to add. So I need to use a range.

Are there any suggestions for a work-around? I have rebooted and copied into a clean spreadsheet - no change!

```
Sub Create_Event_ID_list()
'Looks up last name in column A in Sheet1
'Finds matching last name in column C in Sheet2
'Copies cells in cols A to O in row with matching name
'Pastes copied cells into new row in Sheet3

Dim cell        As Range
Dim Last_name   As Variant
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim NextRow     As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each Last_name In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells

            Set cell = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(Last_name, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, False, False, False)

            If Not cell Is Nothing Then

                cell.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 15).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                'Gives Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error in 24th record

                'cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 
                'Works fine

            End If

        Next Last_name
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The first obvious thing to check is the address of `cell` - is it in column A or B?

Comment: instead of `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.` limit it to the column: `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C").`  You are probably returning a cell in column A or B and then trying to offset it two cells to the left which there are not any.

Comment: Some sample screenshot would be of use.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you, @Scott Craner `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C")` has fixed it!